# captcha works fine in localhost but not in web server

Tags: captcha

here is my coding in my captcha.php

```
<?php
/* captcha.php file*/

    session_start();

    header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2013 00:00:00 GMT"); 
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); 
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    $chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) 
    {
        $randomString .= $chars[rand(0, strlen($chars)-1)];
    }

    $_SESSION['captcha'] = strtolower( $randomString );


    $im = @imagecreatefrompng("captcha_bg.png"); 


    imagettftext($im, 30, 0, 10, 38, imagecolorallocate ($im, 0, 0, 0), 'larabiefont.ttf', $randomString);

    header ('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($im, NULL, 0);
    imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

can somebody help me to find where is the wrong place??? 
I have changed the expired date but it still doesnot work.. please help me..

thanks sorry my english is passif.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is the captcha showing? Will it validate incorrectly? You'll need to be more specific.

Comment: the capctha is only showing the image broken

Answer (score 0):

If it's working fine on your localhost, maybe you are missing some libraries / other configuration in the server?

Maybe you can output:

```
echo phpinfo();
```

and compare possible differences... Also, be sure to have all needed resources on server machine (e.g. larabiefont.ttf , captcha_bg.png ).

Comment: I think because the php version. in my localhost the php version is 5.5.9 but at 000webhost it just 5.2.17. is that the problem??

Comment: I don't think this should cause any problem. You could check if the gd library is correctly set on the server, and if you have copied the captcha_bg.png to the same folder of the php file. And that at least it can be read (check file permissions)

Comment: finally it works when I put './' to the larabiefont.ttf like this './larabiefont.ttf' thanks for responses mates!!